# Swapping values between arrays (php)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form where I will enter one of three words that I have placed in an array, chose a category and when I press send I want another word from another array to show up, the word that shows up should have the same key as the word entered in the form.

This is what I've tried so far, after searching for a while.

```
function wordswap() {
    $word=array('hello','happy','yes');
    $opp=array('bye','sad','no');
    for($y=0;$y<=2;$y++){
        if($text==$word[$y]){ //$text is the word entered in the form
            echo "$opp[$y]";
        }
    }
}
```

When enter "hello" into the form and press send, I want "bye" to show up etc.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should read the documentation on how variables are expanded inside PHP strings. It should explain why your echo doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a mapping instead of two arrays here:

```
function wordswap($text) {
    $wordMap = [
        'hello' => 'bye',
        'happy' => 'sad',
        'yes'   => 'no',
    ];

    return empty($wordMap[$text]) ? null : $wordMap[$text];
}
```

Comment: Why do you still have the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're `echo`ing a string - if you remove the double quotes around `$opp[$y]` then it should work :)

```
function wordswap() {
    $word=array('hello','happy','yes');
    $opp=array('bye','sad','no');
    for($y=0;$y<=2;$y++){
        if($text==$word[$y]){ //$text is the word entered in the form
            echo $opp[$y];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the correct solution, but it looks like it got removed. Here it is:
(link: https://eval.in/137813)

```
function wordswap($input) {
$word=array('hello','happy','yes');
$opp=array('bye','sad','no');

$key = array_search($input, $word);
if (isset($opp[$key])) {
    return $opp[$key];
}

return FALSE;
}

echo wordswap('hello');
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to write your own function. You can do it with only one from standard lib: `str_replace(array('hello','happy','yes'), array('bye','sad','no'), $text);`
Here you have demo: https://eval.in/137815

Comment: please consider adding somne explanation to your answer, explaining how your proposed code will solve the problem, and why the questioner was getting it wrong. This will help others in the future

Comment: This replaces all instances of the words being search for, rather than if they are the exact match.